# Generate GOST 34.10-2001 keypair and save it to some keystore

Tags: java, bouncycastle, keytool, jce, gost3410

Currently I need to generate a keypair for GOST 34.10-2001 signature algorithm. It was pleasant to discover that bouncy castle provider has supported this algorithm, but I can not generate a keypair and save it to any keystore of any type. Currently I tried this command (this command works great if `keyalg` is `DSA` and sigalg is `SHA1withDSA`):

```
keytool -genkey -alias test1 -keyalg ECGOST3410 -keysize 512  -sigalg GOST3411withECGOST3410 \
-keypass test_1 -validity 1000 -storetype JKS -keystore test1.jks -storepass test_1 -v \
-provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar"
```

But I've got an error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown key size.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown key size.
        at sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen.generate(CertAndKeyGen.java:134)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doGenKeyPair(KeyTool.java:1156)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:786)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:172)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:166)
```

Exactly the same error I can see when I try to manipulate keysize or remove `keysize` option from the command. But there is some special case. When I set `keysize` to `256` I've got another error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key size not configurable.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key size not configurable.
        at sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen.generate(CertAndKeyGen.java:134)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doGenKeyPair(KeyTool.java:1156)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:786)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:172)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:166)
```

Currently I have no idea how to generate a keypair and how to save it to a keystore. Also I've got some java code that can generate a key pair for GOST 34.10-2001 algorithm:

```
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECGOST3410", "BC");
kpg.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("GostR3410-2001-CryptoPro-A"));

KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

This code sample uses `ECGenParameterSpec` class to initialize a key pair generator, so may be I should provide it somehow to the keytool (`-providerArg provider_arg` or `-Jjavaoption`)?

P.S. I think that I should provide curve name as some parameter but I can not determine what parameter I should use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will not be able to use keytool and BC to create a keystore with GOST3410 keys.

`sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen` class used by the keytool does not provide an option to initialize the key generator with parameters, while [BC GOST3410 key generator](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/prov/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/ecgost/KeyPairGeneratorSpi.java) requires the initialization with `ECParameterSpec`.

You can create the keypair+certificate and place them into the keystore programmatically:

```
Security.addProvider( new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider() );

KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance( "ECGOST3410", "BC" );
keyPairGenerator.initialize( new ECGenParameterSpec( "GostR3410-2001-CryptoPro-A" ) );
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name subject = new org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name( "CN=Me" );
org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name issuer = subject; // self-signed
BigInteger serial = BigInteger.ONE; // serial number for self-signed does not matter a lot
Date notBefore = new Date();
Date notAfter = new Date( notBefore.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis( 365 ) );

org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder certificateBuilder = new org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(
        issuer, serial,
        notBefore, notAfter,
        subject, keyPair.getPublic()
);
org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder certificateHolder = certificateBuilder.build(
        new org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder( "GOST3411withECGOST3410" )
                .build( keyPair.getPrivate() )
);
org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter certificateConverter = new org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter();
X509Certificate certificate = certificateConverter.getCertificate( certificateHolder );

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );
keyStore.load( null, null ); // initialize new keystore
keyStore.setEntry(
        "alias",
        new KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(
                keyPair.getPrivate(),
                new Certificate[] { certificate }
        ),
        new KeyStore.PasswordProtection( "entryPassword".toCharArray() )
);
keyStore.store( new FileOutputStream( "test.jks" ), "keystorePassword".toCharArray() );
```

Comment: How can I import an existing pfx file which generated with "ECGOST3410" algorithm into a keystore?