# Read JKS with BouncyCastle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, keystore

I have a Java KeyStore (JKS) and I need to read it with BouncyCastle.

I've added `BC` provider at the top of providers list:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
```

If I create KeyStore this way:

```
final KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS", "BC");
```

I get an error:

> java.security.KeyStoreException: JKS not found

If I don't specify a provider, the KeyStore will be created with `Sun` provider and `keystore.aliases()` will contain `EmptyEnumeration`.

As I saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580340/generate-gost-34-10-2001-keypair-and-save-it-to-some-keystore) topic, BouncyCastle can work with JKS

How can I read JKS with BouncyCastle?

Comment: Did you add the following line at the top of your program: `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());`? Refer to [Section 6.0](https://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html).

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yes. I've edited the description

Comment: You are confusing "working with" and "implementing". You normally should not specify the provider in any of the `getInstance()` methods of JCE. Just add the provider with `Security.addProvider()` and the let the JCE find the implementations from any provider. Only the Oracle providers implement the JKS keystore but your `KeyStore.getInstance("JKS", "BC");` forces the JCE to look only  at BouncyCastle's for a JKS implementation which it doesn't have. Also, don't add the BouncyCastle provider at a particular position unless you really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use BKS instead of JKS

```
 KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS", "BC");
```

See section 6.4-Keystore of https://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html

> The Bouncy Castle package has three implementation of a keystore.
>   The first "BKS" is a keystore that will work with the keytool in the same fashion as the Sun "JKS" keystore.

The result will be the same as the Sun provider. If you get an empty list, check the JKS is not empty and you are reading It properly

Comment: I have tried this and in this case `keystore.aliases()` returns `EmptyEnumeration`

Comment: Does your keystore have a certificate? Check with `keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks` Are you reading the keystore in this way?: `keystore.load(inputStream, password);`

Comment: Yes I can see this cert using keytool with the same parameters

Comment: Please, check if the `InputStream` provided to `keystore.load(inputStream, password);` is not null. This method will reset the keystore if the inputstream is null

Comment: I had the wrong path to keystore. KeyStore.getInstance("JKS") works. Thank you